# How to get standards claims of the openid scope "profile" from the ADFS server?

Tags: oauth, openid, adfs, openid-connect

I want the [standard openid claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#StandardClaims) from the scope `profile` with the ADFS service on Windows 20016.

My request call look like:

```
https://myserver/adfs/oauth2/authorize?
     response_type=code&
     client_id=123456&
     redirect_uri=http://localhost/bar&
     scope=openid%20email%20profile
```

The `id_token` contains the follow:

```
{
aud=123456, 
sub=xyz, 
upn=bob@company.local, 
unique_name=COMPANY\bob, 
auth_time=1518686971, 
iss=https://adfs.company.local/adfs, 
exp=1518690571, 
iat=1518686971, 
sid=S-1-5-21-123-456-789-098
}
```

The app was registered with the powershell line:

```
Add-AdfsClient -Name "foo" -ClientId "123456" -RedirectUri @("http://localhost/")
```

How can I get the claims like `email`, `given_name` and `family_name`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried configuring this with the wizard because you can define claims rules on the Web API?

If that doesn't suit, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development) at some examples.